# How to change automatic datetime to a date is given in Json Django?

Tags: python, json, django

I am new to Django. I am trying to save the datetime that is given in the json structure in a start_date field which is auto_now. But it does not work it keeps saving the cuurent date in the database not the date that is given in Json: (  "available_from_date": "2022-07-08 00:00:00.000000"). How can I change that to the date given in json.

In my model.py:

```
   start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In my views.py:

```
   room_status = RoomStatus(
   room =room_obj,
   status=5,
   date_start=room["available_from_date"]
            )
   room_status.save()
```

In json:

```
"room": [
    {
      "available_from_date": "2022-07-08 00:00:00.000000"
    }
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You nee to change the given arguments in you modelfield:

```
start_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

auto_now means that whenever you save an instance, the current time will be saved into the field.

Comment: But I need this start_date field to be auto_now in other case. For example if room is available start_date should be current date if room is unavailabe start_date should be the date that is given in json( "available_from_date": "2022-07-08 00:00:00.000000").

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for:

Comment: start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

Comment: Thank you! it is working now.